# Dymamically created textviews and edittexts

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to render programmitacally an English sentence completion question: Example: I read (this) book, but did not read (that) book. User is supposed to enter their answers(the ones in parenthesis). At the moment, I am only thinking to use RelativeLayout, inside it: Textview (I read) Edittext(this) Textview(book, but did not read) Ediitext(that) Textview(book). But the sentence would be much longer in most cases, it need multiline, here the task becomes more complex to handle. Is there any easier way for this task?

Answer (score 0):

[**FlowLayout**](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) will help you.

You can add `TextView`s and `EditText`s one after another **dynamically** and it will  automatically shown as a sentence:

[image]

Comment: In my case, EditText and TextView mixed. TextView after Editext is starting from new line when I use this library.